# Phone unplugged from laptop result a internal error of ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, android, 20.04, smartphone

Ubuntu 20.04 internal error when i removed the usb cable from the phone with android 9 that was connected to the laptop with this message:
[image]

Ubuntu 20.04 work fine just the internal error appears and i press send to devolopers and a log file is created in var / crash. My question is this was a singular case or it has happened to others ?

Comment: What about choosing to send problem report to the developers? Then they might make a update soon.

Comment: Was the phone mounted at the time? GSConnect or in Nautilus?

Comment: in nautilus was mounted

Comment: sent to developers several times